# What harm can it do to set autocrlf = input on windows?

Tags: git

The reason I'm asking this is I personally feel that setting `autocrlf = input` on windows makes a lot of sense, however, I googled around and didn't find anybody recommending it. It seems people are usually debating between `true` and `false` and `* text=auto`.

So, on Windows, I don't use notepad.exe (which can't handle LF), I always use a code editor. I believe notepad users in this world and git users in this world are different people, so rendering LF properly is not a concern.

By now I have set `autocrlf = input` for over a year, and haven't had issues. I personally feel it's neat, because it avoids all the back and forth conversions by git, feels safer than `true` or `auto`.

I worry if I'm doing something bad. Is there some potential dangers waiting for me?

Comment: In my experience, you can freely mix `input` and `true` on a team based on each user's individual preference without any ill effects. Adding `false` into the fray with one or both of the others can wreak a lot of havoc.

Comment: Stackoverflow recently went terribly wrong... People use answers for asking for clarification and comments for actual answers...

Comment: @mpasko256 - I disagree. My answer does, in fact, answer the question as asked.  It merely *also* points out that the question as asked makes little sense, in case that prompts a revision (in which case the answer will also be updated accordingly).  Whether LightBender's remark is an attempt to answer the question is a matter of their own interpretation; I can't find fault in their decision to make it a comment.

Comment: Something that has gone wrong for me, is in tests - if a test is reading a file from the repo, and expecting LF in assertions, getting CRLF instead can make the test fail. That's not "opinion-based". There is no practical reason to use CRLF on Windows in 2023 - there are no editors that need CRLF, not even "notepad.exe" still needs CRLF. That's not opinion-based either, and frankly this question should be reopened. I have no idea why the Git installer still recommends automatic conversions to CRLF - it's unnecesary and error prone. Line endings sometimes do matter - that's not "opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question really is.  You seem to have copied your "understanding" of what the `autocrlf=input` setting does directly from the documentation; so you *know* what it does, and you know what you want it to do.

The harm would be getting that behavior when it isn't the desired behavior; if you know it's the desired behavior, then what's the issue?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have done it and have not encountered issues, however I worry there might be some potential issues waiting for me in the future, so I want to ask what potential harm it can bring. Do you think it's a valid question, and if yes, how do you suggest me edit my question? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've edited a bit, but now the question is clunkier.

Answer (score 2):

Although @LightBender already answered the question in comment, you can always make some experiments by yourself:

1. In an empty directory, create a new bare repo: `git --bare init`
2. In two other directories, do `git clone <path to bare repo>`
3. In one of them set: `git config core.autocrlf input` 
    
   In the second one `git config core.autocrlf false`
4. Create sample text file containing multiple lines of text and push it into bare repository.
5. Change line ending in first clone and try to push your changes -git will be unable to register any changes and **changed line ending will remain locally.**
6. Also alter single line of text in second clone to provoke a conflict.
7. Observe conflicted file. You can see **whole file marked as conflict instead of single affected line.**

Another exercise would be to do the same in reverse order.

So in short: to prevent from any potential problems, simply **make sure all your contributors use the same line ending convention when pushing into remote.**

Comment: "make sure all your contributors use the same git configuration" - that is very bad advice and defeats the purpose of git's config design.  In the case of autocrlf in particular, the only thing that usually needs to be consistent is the in-repo line ending convention.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Fixed that, thank you. However using consistent configuration usually results in consistent line ending too.

Comment: Hi mpasko256, in your experiment, it seems that the culprit is someone on Windows has 1 set his autocrlf to be false, and 2 set his text editor to use CRLF on pressing Enter, is that right?

Comment: @Quuxuu I performed this experiment on Windows indeed but did it on Notepad++ with displayed special characters so everything was under control :) and yes, your scenario can also cause similar effect